# Sci-fi novel: humans travel to war at the speed of light while kept in tanks of fluid

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’m trying to find the name of a book in which humans are at war with an alien race. While traveling to the galaxy where the fighting is, humans travel at the speed of light while being kept in tanks of fluid to prevent being injured by the sudden speeding up and deceleration. Whilst they are in transit they do not age but for everyone back on Earth time still goes by and when the travelers arrive at their destination everybody they knew back on Earth had long since passed away.

I do not remember much else about the story but I do remember enjoying the book, can anyone can help by supplying me with the novels name and author?

Comment: While those are very common tropes, there's a better-than-decent chance the book is The Forever War by Joe Haldeman?

Comment: Thankyou, it does sound familiar, I’ll check it out

Comment: Please report if it is, so we can mark this question as a duplicate, or if you're sure it's not, since it at least narrows it down by removing the chance of it being one of the most well-known.

Comment: Thanks again, I checked on google and I’m positive that this is the novel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like [*The Forever War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War) by Joe Haldeman, which is a classic. There are a couple of sequels, written much later. The soldiers travel at near light-speed in acceleration tanks like you describe, and then use collapsars as wormholes allowing instant transport across thousands of light years. The relativistic time effects are a big part of the plot.

[image: The Forever War front cover]

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I’ll be sure to check out some of this authors other works.